# Why does NOR need one more output to the multiplexor but NAND not in ALU?

Tags: digital-logic, logic-gates, boolean-algebra

Recently, I was learning "Computer Organization and Design: The Hardware/ Software Interface" riscv 2nd Edition by "David A. Patterson"

In appendix A, A-37 shows the question in "Check Yourself":

> Suppose you wanted to add the operation NOT (a AND b), called **NAND**. How
> could the ALU change to support it?
>
> 1. No change. You can calculate NAND quickly using the current ALU since \$\overline{(a ⋅ b)} = \overline{a} + \overline{b}\$ and we already have NOT a, NOT b, and OR.
> 2. You must **expand the big multiplexor** to add another input, and then add
>    new logic to calculate NAND.

The book answer is 2 (the question in p782 and the answer in p831 can be seen from the [riscv 1st edition](https://bank.engzenon.com/tmp/5e7f7183-219c-4d93-911a-4aaec0feb99b/5dc835ea-b66c-4988-be3f-4d51c0feb99b/Computer_Organization_RiscV_Edition.pdf) where the problem is same as the 2nd edition). But in "FIGURE A.5.9" it uses AND and **NOR** (by \$\overline{(a + b)} = \overline{a} ⋅ \overline{b}\$) with one AND gate.

[image]

---

Q: why is NAND unable to reuse the inverter and the OR gate similar to how NOR does?

Comment: Time to look for corrigenda.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. But it seems [no errata](https://shop.elsevier.com/books/computer-organization-and-design-risc-v-edition/patterson/978-0-12-820331-6) for riscv version but it has one errata in [bookweb](https://booksite.elsevier.com/9780124077263/) for mips 5th edition (appendix A of the former appendix is appendix B of the latter and the [latter errata](https://booksite.elsevier.com/9780124077263/downloads/COD5e_errata_09-2014.pdf) not refers to this question).

Comment: @zgc I don't have the time to reference my copies and think about this, right now. But this "looks like" a good question to ask. (Feelings only and I expect the real answer to be fairly obvious, when written out.) In a few days I might crack the book and look around. Or a week. But not now. Too much else going on. So I'll +1 it in hopes others have the time.

Comment: Looks like the solution given in the book is incorrect. DeMorgan's allows you to compute NAND using the current ALU.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Maybe it is that case as you said.